# NSURLConnection delegate didReceiveData trailing characters in data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've really struggled to figure out why my web service call is riddled with junk data.

I have a UITableViewController that calls the web service and also acts as the NSURLConnectionDelegate.

Here is the delegate method of interest, note the NSLog statements.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"data %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: [data bytes]]);
    NSLog(@"before %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String: self.rawData.bytes]);
    [self.rawData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"after %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String: self.rawData.bytes]);
}
```

Here is the resulting log after a number of attempts:

```
2009-07-10 09:04:20.339 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] data {"items": [], "request": 

"/inventory/delivered.json"}
2009-07-10 09:04:20.339 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] before 
2009-07-10 09:04:20.340 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] after {"items": [], "request": "/inventory/delivered.json"} SundialInvoice] [PID 

2009-07-10 09:04:23.153 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] data {"items": [], "request": "/inventory/delivered.json"}l 4] [Mes
2009-07-10 09:04:23.154 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] before 
2009-07-10 09:04:23.154 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] after {"items": [], "request": "/inventory/delivered.json"} SundialInvoice] [PID 

2009-07-10 09:04:27.913 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] data (null)
2009-07-10 09:04:27.913 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] before 
2009-07-10 09:04:27.914 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] after {"items": [], "request": "/inventory/delivered.json"} SundialInvoice] [PID 

2009-07-10 09:04:30.486 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] data {"items": [], "request": "/inventory/delivered.json"}ice/1.0 CFN
2009-07-10 09:04:30.487 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] before 
2009-07-10 09:04:30.487 SundialInvoice[91493:20b] after {"items": [], "request": "/inventory/delivered.json"} SundialInvoice] [PID
```

Where is the trailing garbage data coming from?  I have run the web service with curl several times and the garbage is not coming from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the garbage comes from the logging:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:self.rawData.bytes]
```

Here you are saying that you want an `NSString` from this C-string (= array of bytes terminated by zero). The problem is that the `bytes` method of `NSData` *does not* return data terminated by a zero, because it’s an ordinary array, not a C-string. Therefore the `NSString` initializer grabs even the bytes after the end of the received `NSData`, until it reaches some zero byte previously stored in memory.

Answer (score 11):

To create an `NSString` from an `NSData`, you should use [`initWithData:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:), like the following:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.rawData
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Before: %@", str);
[str release];
```

Treating `NSData` bytes as C string might cause some security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [rawData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"%@",rawData);
}
```

Also what have you declared rawData as???